# How to submit feedback to GNU ELPA?

Tags: package-repositories

I'm using `cask` and I usually reinstall all my packages every other day. Lately I have noticed a lot of `Bad request` responses from ELPA. I have to retry a few times before all the packages get fetched.

This is not a bug in Emacs-the-application, so the `report-emacs-bug` command seems like the wrong interface. Instead, I want to report a bug about the ELPA service.

Is there a way I can submit some kind of feedback to GNU ELPA about this?

Comment: Which ELPA are you referring? For Gnu ELPA, I guess you can `M-x report-emacs-bug` or use the emacs-devel mailing list.

Comment: GNU Elpa. I have added the details. Hmmm, reporting a bug through the standard report doesn't sound like a good place... Maybe I will try the emacs-devel list.

Comment: Reporting a bug using `report-emacs-bug` is exactly the right thing. How is this not about reporting (what you think is) a bug? (But if you instead want to initiate a development discussion then `emacs-devel` is likely better.)

Comment: My thinking is that this is not an issue inside Emacs per se, but in an external service so filling a bug about it is somehow unrelated. Emacs can work perfectly without packages from ELPA. This is just an external addition. Anyway, thanks for the input.

Comment: Possibly related [help-gnu-emacs thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2019-02/msg00254.html), [continued here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2019-03/msg00000.html). It probably would have been better suited to `emacs-devel` though.

Answer (score 1):

These problems may come from your local Emacs or from the `elpa.gnu.org` server.  The server is managed by a loosely defined group without a central contact point, but AFAIK they all read emacs-devel and/or the bug-gnu-emacs list, so you can bring up the issue on emacs-devel if you think the problem is on the server side or via `M-x report-emacs-bug` when you're not sure.